# JS regexp to match words, exclude words surrounded by slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

This regexp is working in PHP:

```
(?<![\/?$])\bfoo\b
```

I need to make it working in JS, so

```
foo             - need this
<div>foo</div>  - need this

Foo         - dont need this
foobar      - dont need this
/foo/       - dont need this
```

**Update:** [>solution<](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:^|[^\/?$])(\bfoo\b)
```

You can use this and grab the `group` now.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/37

Comment: @Qteb that's why i wrote ,grab the `group 1` and not `match`.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, your example does not working correctly -> https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/38

Comment: @Qteb see on the right side...you can see groups you need to grab them...also why `  foo` is invalid?

Comment: When i'am trying to use substitution, its replace not correct matches, can u fix it?

Comment: @Qteb https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/43 it is working correclty.What other result do you want